# Why is useMemo not rerendering even though the dependancy being passed into it is changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx

So I have a component TaskList:

```
const [incompleteTasks, setIncompleteTasks] = useState<any[]>([]);
  useMemo(() => {
    const filteredTasks = TaskStore.tasks.filter(
      (task: any) => !task.completed
    );
    setIncompleteTasks(filteredTasks);
  }, [TaskStore.tasks]);
```

and the observable state is passed as a dependancy from TaskStore:

```
public tasks: Task[] = [];
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }
  @action setCompleted = (task: Task, completed: number) => {
    const index = this.tasks.indexOf(task);
    if (index !== -1) {
      this.tasks[index].completed = !!completed;
    }
  };
```

I thought the way useMemo() works is that it caches the calculation in the first parameter(so the filtered array), and then the second parameter is the dependancy which triggers a useMemo() to return another calculation of the first parameter if it changes. Is my understanding wrong? Or am I not doing it correctly?

Comment: Is `tasks` in `TaskStore` observable? (Either because you've used `makeObservable` or you've used `@observable` on it?)

Comment: It should be yeah. The makeAutoObservable(this) line makes it observable, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Mobx. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you believe `TaskStore.tasks` to be observable because you're using `makeAutoObservable`, so in theory that shouldn't be the problem. My Mobx is very rusty (I haven't used it in years, though I like the idea of it), but since you're using Mobx, I suspect you want a [computed](https://mobx.js.org/computeds.html), not `useMemo`, for what you're doing. See the end of the answer for an example using Mobx where `incompleteTasks` is a computed.

#### Using `useMemo`

But if you want to use `useMemo`:

Using `useMemo`'s callback to call a state setter is incorrect. Instead, `incompleteTasks` should be the result of `useMemo`, not a state member, because it's *derived* state, not primary state:

```
const incompleteTasks = useMemo(
    () => TaskStore.tasks.filter((task: any) => !task.completed),
    [TaskStore.tasks]
);
```

[`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) will only call your callback if `TaskStore.tasks` changes;¹ otherwise, when called, it will return the previously-returned value instead. So your code only filters when necessary.

Here's a really simple non-Mobx example of derived state:

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useMemo, useEffect } = React;

const initialTasks = [
    { id: 1, text: "first task", completed: false },
    { id: 2, text: "second task", completed: false },
    { id: 3, text: "third task", completed: false },
    { id: 4, text: "fourth task", completed: false },
    { id: 5, text: "fifth task", completed: false },
    { id: 6, text: "sixth task", completed: false },
];

const Task = ({ task, onChange }) => {
    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: { checked } }) => onChange(task, checked);
    return (
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed} onChange={handleChange} /> {task.text}
        </label>
    );
};

const Example = () => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(initialTasks);
    const incompleteTasks = useMemo(() => {
        console.log(`Updating incompleteTasks.`);
        return tasks.filter((task) => !task.completed);
    }, [tasks]);

    const updateTask = useCallback((task, completed) => {
        setTasks((tasks) => tasks.map((t) => (t === task ? { ...t, completed } : t)));
    }, []);

    // A pointless counter just to show that `incompleteTasks` isn't recreated
    // on every render
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);

    // ...code to add/remove tasks not shown for brevity...

    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                Counter: {counter}
            </div>
            <h3>All tasks:</h3>
            <ul>
                {tasks.map((task) => (
                    <li key={task.id}>
                        <Task task={task} onChange={updateTask} />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <h3>Incomplete tasks:</h3>
            <ul>
                {incompleteTasks.map((task) => (
                    <li key={task.id}>
                        <Task task={task} onChange={updateTask} />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<div style="height: 50rem"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Notice how even though the component is re-rendered every time `counter` changes, `incompleteTasks` is only re-calculated when `tasks` changes (for instance, because one of the tasks is marked completed/uncompleted).

#### Using Mobx's `computed`

But I suspect you don't want to use `useMemo` at all. Instead, you probably want to make `incompleteTasks` a Mobx computed. I haven't used Mobx in several years, but here's an example I put together using their documentation, particular [this](https://mobx.js.org/computeds.html), [this](https://mobx.js.org/actions.html), and [this](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html):

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const { makeAutoObservable, action } = mobx;
const { observer, computed } = mobxReactLite;

class TaskStore {
    tasks = [];

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    get incompleteTasks() {
        console.log("Computing incompleteTasks...");
        return this.tasks.filter((task) => !task.completed);
    }
}

const taskStore = new TaskStore();
taskStore.tasks.push(
    { id: 1, text: "first task", completed: false },
    { id: 2, text: "second task", completed: false },
    { id: 3, text: "third task", completed: false },
    { id: 4, text: "fourth task", completed: false },
    { id: 5, text: "fifth task", completed: false },
    { id: 6, text: "sixth task", completed: false }
);

const Task = ({ task, onChange }) => {
    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: { checked } }) => onChange(task, checked);
    return (
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked={task.completed} onChange={handleChange} /> {task.text}
        </label>
    );
};

const Example = observer(({ taskStore }) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    const updateTask = useCallback(action((task, completed) => {
        task.completed = !task.completed;
    }), []);

    // A pointless counter just to show that `incompleteTasks` isn't recreated
    // on every render
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setInterval(() => {
            setCounter((c) => c + 1);
        }, 1000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timer);
        };
    }, []);

    // ...code to add/remove tasks not shown for brevity...

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Counter: {counter}</div>
            <h3>All tasks:</h3>
            <ul>
                {taskStore.tasks.map((task) => (
                    <li key={task.id}>
                        <Task task={task} onChange={updateTask} />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <h3>Incomplete tasks:</h3>
            <ul>
                {taskStore.incompleteTasks.map((task) => (
                    <li key={task.id}>
                        <Task task={task} onChange={updateTask} />
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Example taskStore={taskStore} />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<div style="height: 50rem"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx/6.7.0/mobx.umd.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mobx-react-lite/3.4.0/mobxreactlite.umd.development.js"></script>
```

---

¹ *In theory.* The `useMemo` documentation says it's only a performance optimiation, not a semantic guarantee, but that's all you need for this code.

Comment: Ohhh, I think that makes sense, thank you. So basically, I should be using the state setter on the result of the useMemo rather than the result of the filtered array. But when I try to wrap setIncompleteTasks around the useMemo, it says Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<any[]>'. I assume the result isn't being properly returned, but I can't put a return statement inside it either so I'm not sure why.

Comment: @ChanKim - No, you don't use a state setter **at all** for `incompleteTasks` (that's why it's not in the code above). It's **derived** state (derived from `TaskStore.tasks`).

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I follow.  Bear with me as I'm a newbie, so I have the TaskStore.tasks state which contains the list of tasks to render, shouldn't I have a separate state just for incomplete tasks as well? I don't fully understand what you mean.

Comment: @ChanKim - You don't need a state member for it, because you *derive* (calculate) `incompleteTasks` from `TaskStore.tasks` as necessary. `useMemo` will store the most recently calculated version and if its dependency hasn't changed, it will return that previous version instead of calling your function. So the list of incomplete tasks is stored in `useMemo`'s storage, not state. I've added an example to the answer above (it doesn't use Mobx, but it shows how to derive state with `useMemo`). That said, Mobx has computeds, which you'd probably use instead of `useMemo`.

Comment: @ChanKim - I've updated the answer with an example using Mobx and `computed` rather than `useMemo`. Note that my Mobx is **very** rusty, I haven't used it in years.

Comment: This is an amazing response, there is so much to learn from here. Thank you so much for taking the time to write all this out.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of useMemo is correct. It does cache the result of a calculation between re-renders.
Your code should be more like

```
return useMemo(() => {
    const filteredTasks = TaskStore.tasks.filter(
      (task: any) => !task.completed
    );
    setIncompleteTasks(filteredTasks);
  }, [TaskStore.tasks]);
```